# Ruby key getting replaced, instead of a new key created

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-2.5

```
ruby 2.5
```

I have the following code:

```
test = {'primer' => 'grey'}
layers = ["tan","burgundy"]
fillers = ["blue","yellow"]
layers.each do |l|
    fillers.each do |f|
      test[l] = {} if !test.respond_to?(l)
      test[l][f] = {} if !test[l].respond_to?(f)
    end
end
```

When I run it in irb, I get the following:

```
{"primer"=>"grey", "tan"=>{"yellow"=>{}}, "burgundy"=>{"yellow"=>{}}}
```

I am expecting:

```
{"primer"=>"grey", "tan"=>{"blue"=>{},"yellow"=>{}}, "burgundy"=>{"blue"=>{},"yellow"=>{}}}
```

Why does the first respond_to produce the key, when the second one, replaces the previous key?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
test.respond_to?(l)
```

does not make sense. `l` is a string, and `respond_to?` returns true if the receiver has a method of the name represented by this string. Since the receiver is a Hash and a Hash has no methods Hash#tan and Hash#burgundy, the test will always fail.

Maybe you want to do a `test.has_key?(l)` instead....

Comment: My question was why is it responding to the first respond_to but not the next one

Comment: **All** the `respond_to` will return false, hence the `if` clauses will **always** be true. The end result is the same as if you would have written no `if` clause at all. That's why you get your result. You can easily verify it if you place a `p test` after each assignment to the `test` Hash.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper : With other words: In effect, you execute `layers.each { |l| fillers.each { |f| test[l] = {}; test[l][f] = {} }}`, which with your input data results in `{"primer"=>"grey", "tan"=>{"yellow"=>{}}, "burgundy"=>{"yellow"=>{}}}`.

Comment: Yes, I can see now how that happened

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the hash `{a: 1}`, having a key `:a` doesn't make the hash object respond to `:a`. `hash.respond_to?(:a)` would still return `false`. You want to check if a key exists, this can be done using [`has_key?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F)/[`key?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F).

```
layers.each do |l|
  fillers.each do |f|
    test[l] = {} unless test.has_key?(l)
    test[l][f] = {} unless test[l].has_key?(f)
  end
end
```

However since you set the values to a hash, which is a truthy value. You could also use `||=` which only assigns a value if the current value is falsy. `test[:non_existing_key]` will result in `nil` (unless a default is set).

Meaning the above can be replaced with:

```
layers.each do |l|
  fillers.each do |f|
    test[l] ||= {}
    test[l][f] ||= {}
  end
end
```

You could simplify this whole statement with the use of [`product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-product) which combines the two loops for you.

```
layers.product(fillers) do |layer, filler|
  test[layer] ||= {}
  test[layer][filler] ||= {}
end
```